# Locate parent element that contains specific child element

Tags: c#, html, xml, selenium, xpath

What I would like to do is to locate all the parent elements that contain a specific child.

```
<tr>
 <i class="myClass"> </i>
</tr>
```

So in this case I would like to locate all `tr` tags that contain `i` tag with this specific class.

Is there any possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers thus far are more complicated than necessary.  This simple XPath will select the `tr` elements with child `i` elements with a `class` attribute equal to `myClass`:

```
//tr[i/@class='myClass']
```

If `i` was just an example, and really the goal is to select `tr` elements with *any* child element with the given `@class` attribute value, then this'll work instead:

```
//tr[*/@class='myClass']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use parent axis in xpath

```
//i[class="myClass"]/parent::tr
```

The above one selects parent elements having tag tr. To select all parents

```
//i[class="myClass"]/parent::*
```

please find xpath axes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp)

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using XPath.

```
//*[@class='myClass']/parent::tr
```